# Classifying NP Completeness and Hardness

Tags: polynomials, np, reduction, np-complete, np-hard

Choose the correct statement(s):

- (A) If `X` is an NP-complete problem, then `X` is an NP problem
- (B) If `X` is an NP-complete problem, then `X` is an NP-hard
- (C) Let `X` be an NP-complete problem. If `X` can polynomial reduce to a problem `Y`, then `Y` is an NP-complete.
- (D) Let `X` be an NP-complete problem. If `Y` can polynomial reduce to a problem `X`, then `Y` is an NP-complete.
- (E) Let `X` be an NP-complete problem. If `X` can polynomial reduce to a problem `Y`, then `Y` is an NP-hard.

My answer is (A)(B)(C)(E):

- (A)(B) : X belongs to NP-complete, means X belongs to NP and NP-hard
- (C) true
- (D) Y may be P, NP-hard or NP-complete
- (E) Y is an NP-complete, and it also is an NP-hard

---

Is answer true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some corrections:

(C) False. Y is NP-hard, but not necessarily in NP.

(D) False. Y is in NP, not necessarily NP-complete.

(E) True, but Y is no necessarily NP-complete.